# How to detect which option was selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this multiple select tag:

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And I have a change action:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    alert(e.option???)
})
```

How can I detect which option was changed? I want to know which option was selected/unselected as last. So If I have selected "volvo" and I select "opel" I want to use in the alert only opel.

Comment: Whats the objective?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    $('option:selected', this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector at this context,

```
$('select').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log($(":selected", this));
});
```

Since you are using multiple `select` element, the `:selected` selector's result would be more than one `option` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($(e.target).val());
})
```